# How to get buildnumber / revision from Assembly? (4th digit)

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

Our build process updates the forth digit (buildnumber or revision) of the version number on every build.

[image]

I'm using the following code to try and get the version so that it can be displayed on the splash screen and about page.

```cs
var version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version;
var programName = "Version: " + version;
```

**How come the 4th digit in the version number is always zero, and what can I change to get it to property reflect the build number?**

[image]

Comment: Given code will return value of `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]` (defined in `AssemblyInfo.cs` typically), can you show how exactly you set this attribute up? (not sure what shown screenshot with `MCA` means). Another thing what I can think of is what `GetEntryAssembly` returns (I am using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any assembly has two metadatas: the assembly version and the file version. The assembly version I don't know exactly how to take it. It seems that there is an **AssemblyVersionAttribute** but when I try to search for it, a null reference is returned.

But the File version you can take using this code:

```
public static Version GetAssemblyVersion (Assembly asm)
{
    var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(asm, typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), true) as AssemblyFileVersionAttribute;
    return new Version(attribute.Version);
}
```

Generally, I use to synchronize so that file version = assembly version every time so I can grab assembly version using this code. Third party libraries, from my experience I can tell that are following this pattern also.

Comment: You could use the `System.Version` class instead of parsing it yourself.

Comment: I realized this after seeing @sinatr's comment. I am only updating the first 3 digits in the AssemblyInfo, but the FileVersion get's the build number. [*facepalm*](http://goo.gl/eY1XTm)

Comment: As it turns out, [my module](https://github.com/FutureStateMobile/poshBAR/blob/master/src/poshBAR/Update-AssemblyVersions.ps1#L41) was masking the problem for me.